# How to loop video in watchOS 2?

Tags: video, watchos-2, wkinterfaceobject

How do you loop a watchOS 2 video so it plays over and over forever?

All I have right now is the video playing once. What code should I add to change that?

Comment: What language?  What method are you using to play the video?  Please show some code, so people don't have to ask questions to answer a question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop a [`WKInterfaceMovie`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMovie_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceMovie/setLoops:) by setting `setLoops` to YES/true.

> Sets a Boolean value indicating whether the movie plays in a continuous loop. Specify YES to play the movie in a continuous loop or NO to play the movie once and then stop playback.

**Swift sample code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var moviePlayer: WKInterfaceMovie!
...
moviePlayer.setLoops(true)
```